# How to copy MenuItem from one ContextMenu to another ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

How do I copy a MenuItem I created in one ContextMenu and copy it so that I can use it in a second ContextMenu?

I tried to copy it directly and removing it, but I get *Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one.*

```
foreach(MenuItem mi in menuOptions.Items) { 
    entityRightClick.Items.Add(mi);
    menuOptions.Items.Remove(mi);
}
```

I tried grabbing the MenuItem using the ItemContainerGenerator, it gave me a blank MenuItem (Debugger says that it is null)

```
for(int i = 0; i < menuOptions.Items.Count; i++) {
    MenuItem temp = new MenuItem();
    temp = menuOptions.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as MenuItem;
    entityRightClick.Items.Add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your error message, I'd expect this to work (though I haven't tested it):

```
foreach(MenuItem mi in menuOptions.Items) 
{      
     menuOptions.Items.Remove(mi);
     entityRightClick.Items.Add(mi);
 }
```

Comment: That gives me `System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` when I do that.

Comment: doh! yup, of course, cos the foreach loop :) So do this: List<MenuItem> items = new List<MenuItem>(menuOptions.Items); menuOptions.Items.Clear; foreach(MenuItem mi in items) { entityRightClick.Items.Add; } //Sorry for the formatting

Comment: Would it be easier to make the menuOptions a List<MenuItems> instead? Would it bind the MenuItems to the List, like it does with ContextMenu?

Comment: Awesome sweet. If I use a List<MenuItem> instead, then it won't bind to anything yet until I actually add it when I need it.

Comment: @Kell Thanks for your solution, but I needed to make a `List<object>` because the ItemsCollection may contain not only `MenuItem` Objects (Seperators for example).